How to add a leading zero?
How can I add a leading zero to a text input?
const day = ref('');

<input type="text" v-model="day" />


So, I've tried a watcher:
watch(day, (newValue) => {
    day.value = newValue.toString().padStart(2, '0');
});

This works, but if I type, 1 it turns into 01 as expected but if I highlight the input and hit 1 again, it is not transformed with the leading zero.
Is there anyway to make this work?

May be specific to a browser, but generally not reproducible https://play.vuejs.org/#eNp9kc1uwjAQhF9l5UuClIb+nWhAaisO7aGtStWTL1FYIDSxLXsTQFHevWujUA4VOUTambH1jbcTj8akbYNiIjJX2NIQOKTGzKQqa6MtQQcWVwnscio20MPK6hoiPhFJJVWhlSNY5geY+lgcRaMHr4d0zHoCscLdd141OILpDDqpgD920taLfG7wU9ILsqVax6PU5MsF5Zbi2wSi63Bp73/Z+AjJeDwQ1qbKCXkCyDY3s64LLH2fjXkKaqlMQ0AHg1MpCPckBbRXtV5ixQKneR5zNBuf3SYSQY67rcp1unVa8esEcCkKXZuyQvtuqOTuUkyGSlLkVaV3r0Ej22Ay6MUGi59/9K3be02KD4sObYtSnDwuv0Zm9fZ88Ra4TybTNxWnL5if6HTVeMZj7KlRS8Y+ywXal7BjfvMvN98TKjeU8qA+2Ye8FLzw5wvV/3Dv0vtwjhcm+l9qfcea

@EstusFlask you are correct, thanks, it must be my code, I'm using a custom <InputText v-model="day" /> which has const model = defineModel({     type: [Number, String], }); on it, so it must be this causing issues.

What's InputText? Is "const model" outside the component or inside? Please, provide a way to reproduce. What you describe is a different case, defineModel results in a component with no own state, so it's synced differently.

The problem is when the component is used.
The solution is to use nextTick():
watch(day, async newValue => {
  await nextTick();
  day.value = newValue.toString().padStart(2, '0');
});

Vue SFC Playground
